# jquery getscript() and const variables (possibly scope issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, constants, getscript

Why in this example i get Uncaught ReferenceError: CONST1 is not defined

**consts.js**

```
const CONST1 = "hello";
```

**sample.js**

```
jQuery.getScript("consts.js', function() {
    alert(CONST1);
});
```

I guess it has something to do with scope. But since getScript uses global scope i cannot understand why this fails.

P.S. By using var instead of const it seems to work. But i cannot get the exact reason.

Comment: It is a scope issue. The same would occur if you used ESM or require

Comment: thans for the reply! Can you elaborate a little more? Isn't it applied in global scope? Also why var works?

Comment: <https://stackabuse.com/the-difference-between-var-let-and-const-in-javascript-and-best-practices/> this article explains pretty well the scoping difference between `var` and `const`

Comment: for a better answer could u pls make a sample.

Comment: I have already provided some sample code. I can understand the difference between const and var. But in the given example I can't understand why const is not defined.